# MIME type for serialized R objects

Tags: r, http, content-type

[OpenCPU](http://www.opencpu.org) currently uses `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` when serving serialized R objects (i.e. data saved from `serialize` or `saveRDS`). For example:

```
curl -v https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/MASS/data/cats/rds 2>&1 \
| grep Content-Type

< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location, X-ocpu-session, Content-Type, Cache-Control
```

However it would be nice for clients and other OpenCPU servers to distinguish between an arbitrary blob and rds objects when exchanging data, using a designated MIME type.

Question: what would be the appropriate `Content-Type` for serialized R objects? For example something like:

- `application/r-rds`
- `application/r-serialized-object`
- ...

Note that [RFC8848](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) now advises against using an `X-` prefix and states that:

> Creators of new parameters to be used in the context of application
> protocols:
>
> 1. SHOULD assume that all parameters they create might become
>    standardized, public, commonly deployed, or usable across
>    multiple implementations.